# How to build a Pageviewbuilder with Months to navigate in bottomNaviationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

In my code below, i have 3 tabs , in each tab at the bottom I want to show the month , basically each page is the current month which will hold the data(hours ) for that month, now i have implemented the bottomNavigationBar, when i click on forward icon button i want it to go atleast 3 months next to current month for example (today is August, go till September, October, November) next when i hit the back button i want it to go till the starting month of the current year , for example August -July...January,

But now, I can only go back 1 month for some reason it wont go past July
what is wrong with the logic could you please update the code ?

```
import 'package:bha_roster/presentation/my_colors.dart';
import 'package:bha_roster/utils/config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pluto_grid/pluto_grid.dart';

class CrewHours extends StatefulWidget {
  const CrewHours({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CrewHoursState createState() => _CrewHoursState();
}

class _CrewHoursState extends State<CrewHours> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  late PageController _pageController;
  int _currentPageIndex = 1;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _currentPageIndex);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: _tabController,
            indicator: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
              color: MyColors.primarySwatch,
            ),
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            indicatorColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 102, 249, 4),
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: const [
              Tab(text: 'Captain'),
              Tab(text: 'First Officer'),
              Tab(text: 'Cabin Crew'),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _pageController,
              onPageChanged: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _currentPageIndex = index;
                });
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final now = DateTime.now();
                final month = now.month + index - 1;
                final year = now.year + (month - 1) ~/ 12;
                final monthName = getMonthName(month);
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text('$monthName $year'),
                  ),
                  body: Column(
                    children: [
                      // const SizedBox(height: 16),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Center(child: Text('$monthName $year')),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                          onPressed: () {
                            final newPageIndex = _currentPageIndex - 1;
                            if (newPageIndex < 12) {
                              _pageController.animateToPage(
                                newPageIndex,
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                        Text('${getMonthName(now.month + _currentPageIndex - 1)} ${now.year}'),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                          onPressed: () {
                            final newPageIndex = _currentPageIndex + 1;
                            if (newPageIndex < 12) {
                              _pageController.animateToPage(
                                newPageIndex,
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: 12,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  String getMonthName(int month) {
    switch (month) {
      case 1:
        return 'January';
      case 2:
        return 'February';
      case 3:
        return 'March';
      case 4:
        return 'April';
      case 5:
        return 'May';
      case 6:
        return 'June';
      case 7:
        return 'July';
      case 8:
        return 'August';
      case 9:
        return 'September';
      case 10:
        return 'October';
      case 11:
        return 'November';
      case 12:
        return 'December';
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }
}
```

Summary: so, for every year i want to show the page of all the months passed and 1 month forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// add dependency by run command: dart pub add intl
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class CrewHours extends StatefulWidget {
  const CrewHours({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CrewHoursState createState() => _CrewHoursState();
}

class _CrewHoursState extends State<CrewHours>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  late PageController _pageController;
  /// initial index of current month between month intervals
  int _currentPageIndex = 1;
  /// Index of current month between month intervals
  int nowAtIndex = 0;

  /// month intervals
  int timeSpanCount = 1;
  /// months after current month
  int afterNowMonth = 3;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    /// get start time
    DateTime startTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM").parse("2019-01");
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat("yyyy-MM");
    final DateTime date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    final str = formatter.format(date);
    final endTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM").parse(str);

    /// calculate intervals of current month with start time
    while (startTime.isBefore(endTime)) {
      timeSpanCount++;
      startTime = DateTime(startTime.year, startTime.month + 1);
    }

    _currentPageIndex = timeSpanCount;
    nowAtIndex = timeSpanCount;
    timeSpanCount += afterNowMonth;


    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _currentPageIndex);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: _tabController,
            indicator: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
            ),
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            indicatorColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 102, 249, 4),
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: const [
              Tab(text: 'Captain'),
              Tab(text: 'First Officer'),
              Tab(text: 'Cabin Crew'),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _pageController,
              onPageChanged: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _currentPageIndex = index;
                });
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DateTime date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                    DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);

                DateTime time = DateTime(date.year, date.month + (index - nowAtIndex));
                final year = time.year;
                final month = time.month;
                print('item build ${date} ${index - nowAtIndex}, $year , $month');
                final monthName = getMonthName(month);
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text('$monthName $year'),
                  ),
                  body: Column(
                    children: [
                      // const SizedBox(height: 16),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Center(child: Text('$monthName $year')),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                          onPressed: () {
                            final newPageIndex = _currentPageIndex - 1;
                            if (newPageIndex > 0) {
                              _pageController.animateToPage(
                                newPageIndex,
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                        Text('${getMonthName(month)} ${year}'),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                          onPressed: () {
                            final newPageIndex = _currentPageIndex + 1;
                            if (newPageIndex < timeSpanCount) {
                              _pageController.animateToPage(
                                newPageIndex,
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: timeSpanCount,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  String getMonthName(int month) {
    switch (month) {
      case 1:
        return 'January';
      case 2:
        return 'February';
      case 3:
        return 'March';
      case 4:
        return 'April';
      case 5:
        return 'May';
      case 6:
        return 'June';
      case 7:
        return 'July';
      case 8:
        return 'August';
      case 9:
        return 'September';
      case 10:
        return 'October';
      case 11:
        return 'November';
      case 12:
        return 'December';
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }
}
```